# File Location of the Image in ImageView

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafxports

`ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(new Image("icons/login.png"));`

I used JavafxPorts to deploy my JavaFX application to my Android device, JavaFXPorts has its own way of convention, I just want to get the complete **File Location** of the `login.png`. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't get the "file location" from an `Image`, because the `Image` might not have been created from a file. (For example, it may have been created from a different kind of resource, such as an http resource or an entry in a jar file, or it may be a `WritableImage` that was just created on the fly.)

If you are creating an image from a file, then you need to create the file object and retain a reference to it when you create the image:

```
// reference to file with image:
File imageFile = new File("icons/login.png");

Image image = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you try this ...

```
Image image = new Image("flower.png");
ImageView iv3 = new ImageView();
iv3.setImage(image);
```